# Facebook Sdk version and support:appcompat version issue

Tags: android, facebook, android-support-library, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using these Dependencies in my android project.

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
        compile "com.hanks:htextview-evaporate:0.1.1"
        compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Now the problem is that

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
```

It is showing me the warning (after updating version of all libraries) like this :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

And when I am removing Facebook Sdk Lib.  `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27'` .

Everything works fine but obviously I need it.I dont know what should i do can anyone help me.

Comment: You need to  compile all library which You are getting on hover when you point mouse on error.

Comment: But whatever writen on it is just an "EXAMPLE".

Comment: its not give just example word...it will give you name of  library too which you need to include in your gradle for compile.

Comment: I got you, thanks, but facebook need to update there sdk.

Comment: You welcome ! You can accept my answer if it have solved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because Facebook Sdk is using another revision of Google support libraries. You need to compile all library which error warn you on mouse hover with same version as your gradle have support library.

Comment: No Just include library which You get in mouse hover and use version v7:25.4.0 as you are using in your gradle.

Comment: Yes i included them too but doesn't work so i am using v7.25.3.1 which is working perfectly.

Comment: I have faced similar issue before with another library and it was solved with this way. It should work fine if you include all library which we get in warning and must have same version. Thanks